OverlayEntry with dynamic and maximum size
In my flutter app I want to display search results under a search bar overlaid over the rest of the page (a form with many text entries). The search results come from an API and there may be any number of results between 0 and 10. I want the list of search results to be as big as necessary with a specified maximum height (if there are more results than the user should be able to scroll through the list). Let's assume it should have a maximum height of: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5. I'm using OverlayEntry with a CompositedTransformTarget and a CompositedTransformFollower:
  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower(
          link: _layerLink,
          showWhenUnlinked: false,
          offset: const Offset(0, 50),
          child: Material(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: searchResults.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(searchResults[index]['name']),
                  onTap: () {
                    pointController.text = searchResults[index]['name'];
                    print(searchResults[index]);
                    _hideOverlay();
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

My problem now is how to make the size of the Listview be dynamic based on the number of results, while still having a maximum height. I have set the shrinkwrap: true property in the ListView, but that alone does not seem to do it.
If I set the height property in the Positioned widget (currently commented out in the code example), the search results take up the space I intended and I can scroll through the results if there are more that don't fit in that space, but the list always takes that size even if there are only few (or none) results to display, leaving me with a lot of ugly white space in that case. The size is not dynamic.
If I don't set the height property at all, the size is dynamic, but if there are many results it can "overflow" the bottom of the page and it it doesn't scroll at all, meaning there are items, that are not displayed and that I cannot reach. I tried implementing a SingleChildScrollView or a Scrollbar to solve this, but it did not change anything. I added a screenshot of this case to the post.
How can I make my Overlay dynamic based on the size it takes to display the search results, while still having a maximum height?


tried wrapping Materail with ConstrainedBox?

@pskink That actually did it, thank you!

sure, your welcome

I solved the problem by wrapping the Material widget in a ConstrainedBox and setting a maxHeight constraint:
  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower(
          link: _layerLink,
          showWhenUnlinked: false,
          offset: const Offset(0, 50),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: searchResults.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(searchResults[index]['name']),
                    onTap: () {
                      pointController.text = searchResults[index]['name'];
                      print(searchResults[index]);
                      _hideOverlay();
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

